# Can I check the IEnumerable<T> before using yield return

Tags: c#, yield-return

I have am creating an IEnumerable from a stream by creating each record one by one. Is there a way to check my current results if the Id already exists then I don't want to add the currently read record into the set.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; }
    public string Hours { get; set; }

    public static Employee Create(IDataRecord record)
    {
        return new Employee
        {
           Name = record["name"],
           Country = record["country"],
           Rank = record["rank"],
           Hours = record["hours"],
        };
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees(TextReader stream)
{
    using (var reader = MyLibraryFunction(stream)
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
           yield return Employee.Create(reader);
       }
    }
}

var result = GetEmployees(stream);
```

Edit: This is a simplified example. I actually want to know if I can access the existing records in the set. If it already exists, I would like to simply update one field (add the number of hours) in Employee, if it does not exist then it should be added.

Comment: Why don't you keep a list of ID's and check if it already exists before returning it?

Comment: Would it not be better to find out why `MyLibraryFunction` is returning multiples items with the same ID?

Comment: This was a simplified example. I actually just want to know if it's possible to check the created list before inserting an element - or rather, if I can access the existing set of elements?

Comment: @user3710760 There is no created list.  The code that consumes the enumerable doesn't have to store all the results anywhere.  All the compiler does is generate a state machine to enumerate results one at a time.  It doesn't store a history unless you tell it to (by creating your own list internally).

Answer (score 7):

Use hashset of all yielded object ID`s :

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees(TextReader stream)
{
    var exisiting = new HashSet<int>();
    using (var reader = MyLibraryFunction(stream)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var employee = Employee.Create(reader);
            if (exisiting.Add(employee.Id)) {
                yield return employee;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the Contains check and make the code `if (exisiting.Add(employee.Id))`. The function `HashSet<T>.Add(T item)` returns `false` if the item was already in the collection. Doing a `Contains` then a `Add` makes it check the collection twice.

Comment: Chris Pitman is right but HashSet is better than the list in this case because it has O(1) search complexity.

Comment: Why not `yield return emplyee;` instead of creating a second object.

Comment: I updated my question. Is there a way to update the existing list with the current row's value?

Comment: In that case you need to move your populated items set `var exisiting = new HashSet<Employee>();` outside the GetEmployees() method and pass it as a parameter (`GetEmployees(TextReader stream, HashSet<Employee> exisiting)`). After that you can add some additional logic. I also advise you to create the overload for `Employee.GetHashCode()` method to simplify search (if you plan to search by name you can return `Name.GetHashCode()` value).